# function of == in println()

Tags: java, equals, println

```
String literal1 = "java"; 
String object = new String("java"); 
String literal2 = "java";

System.out.println("result 1 = " + (literal1 == object) ); 
System.out.println("result 2 = " + literal1.equals(object)); 
System.out.println("result 3 = " + literal1 == object); 
System.out.println("result 4 = " + literal1.equals(object));
System.out.println("result 5 = " + literal1 == literal2); 
System.out.println("result 6 = " + literal1.equals(literal2));
```

**Expected output**

```
result 1 = false
result 2 = true
result 3 = false
result 4 = true
result 5 = false
result 6 = true
```

**output obtained**

```
result 1 = false
result 2 = true
false
result 4 = true
false
result 6 = true
```

When this line

**System.out.println("result 5 = " + literal1 == literal2);**

is changed to

**System.out.println("result 5 = " + (literal1 == literal2));**

**Output**

```
result 5 = true
```

**Could anyone please explain why this is happening?**

Comment: @NPE: in general yes but not for string literals, and string constant expressions; see JLS 3.10.5

Answer (score 3):

It happens because expressions are evaluated left-to-right so it will first concatenate your string (i.e. `"result 3 = " + literal1`) and then check for *truthiness* (i.e. `== object`), hence printing only `false` because the result of the concatenation is not of the same value as `object`.

In the first (and last) example (`"result 1 = " + (literal1 == object)`) you direct the default evaluation with brackets forcing `(literal == object)` to evaluate separately **before** the concatenation which is why it prints `false` only for that evaluation, concatenated with the string preceding it.

Comment: Ha! This would be a neat question for some "intro to java" course.

Comment: Sorry, I have to down-vote because of the blatantly false statement in the first line. `+` is evaluated before `==` because of *operator precedence*, not because of left-to-right *evaluation order*.

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR: it's precedence, not left-to-right**

Java does have a rule that *operands* are evaluated left-to-right, but that has no effect here.

Also in Java all binary (meaning two-operand, not bitwise) operators other than assignment are left-associative, but that does not apply here because associativity only matters when operators have the same precedence.

What matters here is that `+` has higher [precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2) than `==` so as VietDD says

```
System.out.println("result 5 = " + literal1 == literal2);
# is equivalent to
System.out.println(("result 5 = " + literal1) == literal2);
# which is false because they aren't the same object
```

which happens to be the same as grouping to the left.

But if we consider instead

```
System.out.println(literal1 == literal2 + " is result 5!");
# THAT is equivalent to
System.out.println(literal1 == (literal2 + " is result 5!"));
# ditto
```

which happens to be the same as grouping to the *right*.

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println("result 3 = " + literal1 == object);
>
> System.out.println("result 5 = " + literal1 == literal2);

is equivalent to

> System.out.println( ( "result 3 = " + literal1 ) == object);
>
> System.out.println( ( "result 5 = " + literal1 ) == literal2);

It's **String Concatenation**

1. The expression is evaluated left to right.
2. If either operand is a String, **+** means **concatenation**

You can try this :

> > System.out.println( 1 + 2 + "3");
>
> Output :
>
> > 33

1 + 2 = 3

3 + "3" = "33"

And

> > System.out.println( "1" + 2 + 3);
>
> Output:
>
> > 123

"1" + 2 = "12"

"12" + 3 = "123

Comment: *"The expression is evaluated left to right."* Misleading: The *operands* are evaluated left-to-right, but the *operators* are evaluated according to their *precedence* and *associativity*.