# What is the difference between , System.out.println("s1 == s2 is:" + s1 == s2) and System.out.println(s1 == s2)?

Tags: java, string

I created two String variables and now i compared both variables using '==' operator and printing the results.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [function of == in println()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335509/function-of-in-println)

Comment: Don't ever use `==` to compare two strings in Java.  You'll just get confused.  Use `string1.equals(string2)` instead.

Comment: On another note, things like this become much clearer when you use `printf` instead of `println`.

Comment: Please don't use images when you don't have to.  Instead, copy and format the information in the image as text.

Comment: Hint: Operator Precedence, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html, use `()`

Comment: please consider  [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15244370)

Answer (score 6):

In the first case you are comparing

```
("s1 == s2 is:" + s1) == s2
```

Comment: in other words, probably original should be (corrected) `"s1 == s2 is:" + (s1 == s2)`